# Programmatcally set value of formControl in Model Driven Form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

How do I get my bottom line of the below function to set the value of the categories form field?

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.findForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        categories: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
        distanceNumber: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
        distanceUnit: ['kilometers', [<any>Validators.required]],
        keywords: ['lemon', [<any>Validators.required]],
    });

    this.findForm.controls['categories'].updateValueAndValidity("shoe");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
this.findForm.get('categories').setValue("shoe");
```